# How can I avoid that PropertyChanged event is not triggered while editing the field

Tags: c#, xaml, wcf, binding

I have a custom field and I don't want that property changed event is triggered while I am writing a number or text.

I know that it can be added Delay to XAML.

```
<CustomTextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Delay=500}"/>
```

But this solution is not enough for me, I want that whenever I define a CustomTextBlock  the delay is added automatically and not the developer should add every time.

Is there a way to do this?

or is this a good solution:
[How to wait for WPF Binding Delay to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31016139/how-to-wait-for-wpf-binding-delay-to-complete#answer-31023367)

Comment: I know it is not what you are asking, but I would like to note that  you can also use `Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"` . With this, the event will only be triggered when you leave the field. Maybe it fits your needs better. Btw, you probably want a TextBox, not a TextBlock.

Comment: Yes but this is not the solution that I am searching. If a user is writing something and stop for 500ms, I want that the event is triggered.

Comment: I think that `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus` is default for most controls so if you've got it different, i.e. `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in your `CustomTextBlock` then can't the delay be added in to your `Style` for that?

Comment: Yeh that is the only thing that I found. There is no other way to do.